Email template styles not rendering in GMAIL app when "conversation view" is toggled and the template is added to a folder
I have recently created a HTML email template design for a client, which is displaying as expected. However if "conversation view" is enabled in settings (for gmail app), emails from the same sender are added to a folder.
Once an email is added to a folder, only the styles of the first email in the folder is properly displayed. For some unknown reason, most styles of the older templates in the folder don't work.
I find this very weird, as before I enabled "conversation view" gmail was able to display my email perfectly, which demonstrated that my css was processable by gmail. Why does it not work when an email is simply added to a folder, furthermore why does the first (latest) email in the folder work fine?
I haven't found any similar experiences online, any assistance would be appreciated.
Here is my styles tag:
<head>
  <title> **REDACTED** </title>
  <!--[if !mso]><!-->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style type="text/css">
    #outlook a {
      padding: 0;
    }

    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    }

    table,
    td {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
      mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
    }

    img {
      border: 0;
      height: auto;
      line-height: 100%;
      outline: none;
      text-decoration: none;
      -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
    }

    p {
      display: block;
      margin: 13px 0;
    }
  </style>
  <!--[if mso]>
        <noscript>
        <xml>
        <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
          <o:AllowPNG/>
          <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
        </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
        </xml>
        </noscript>
        <![endif]-->
  <!--[if lte mso 11]>
        <style type="text/css">
          .mj-outlook-group-fix { width:100% !important; }
        </style>
        <![endif]-->
  <!--[if !mso]><!-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="**REDACTED**" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <style type="text/css">
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,500,700);
    @import url(**REDACTED**);
  </style>
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <style type="text/css">
    @media only screen and (min-width:480px) {
      .mj-column-per-100 {
        width: 100% !important;
        max-width: 100%;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <style media="screen and (min-width:480px)">
    .moz-text-html .mj-column-per-100 {
      width: 100% !important;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <style type="text/css">
  </style>
  <style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
      font-family: Kollektif;
      src: url('https://assets.ctfassets.net/o5bu645mjc1y/5AV8oj7IcyYPYkIXEWRqiA/98949e1b81fe43051327852981215bda/Kollektif.woff') format('woff');
      font-weight: normal;
    }

    @font-face {
      font-family: Kollektif;
      src: url('https://assets.ctfassets.net/o5bu645mjc1y/6HL2rvC2WfC56MU593CAAA/89bcbfe0e6bb829f152e26ef276dc109/Kollektif-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .main-section {
      background-size: 100% auto;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    .main-section {
      height: 298px;
      background: url(**REDACTED**) top 32px left 50% no-repeat, url(**REDACTED**) bottom 10px right 50% no-repeat, url(**REDACTED**) center no-repeat;
      background-size: auto, 131px 133px, cover;
    }

    @media (min-width: 640px) {
      .main-section {
        height: 400px;
        background: url(**REDACTED**) center no-repeat;
        background-size: auto, 131px 133px, cover;
      }
    }

    .cta>table>tbody>tr>td>a {
      width: 247px;
      height: 44px;
      border-radius: 0 !important;
      background: url(**REDACTED**) top 0 right 0 no-repeat !important;
      background-size: 247px 44px !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

I have tried adding meta tags from other templates that don't share this problem but to no avail. At one point I though it might be because of background: url();, but why would it display fine normally and only break when added to a folder?
Note - The above HTML is converted from MJML.

I'm seeing the same behavior. CSS styles break on subsequent messages viewed in conversation view. I cant fing any documentation of the behavior anywhere, only random complaints.
